# WordPress test site is slow despite good scores on several page speed sites

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed

I am developing a website for a car rental company and am using a subdomain for testing. The site is very slow on all browsers (and on the backend) despite high score on Pingdom, PageSpeed Insights, and GTmetrix. I'm not new to WordPress and page speed and have been able to achieve speed with the use of plugins and the right hosting.

I am using the Avada theme with the following plugins (I have already removed each plugin individually to see if any one of them was the culprit):

Autoptimize
JCH Optimize
Ninja Forms
Justified Image Grid
W3 Total Cache (used with maxCDN)
WP Migrate DB
WP-Optimize
wpMandrill

Our hosting provider is HostGator but I want to use Pagely.

Here is our [Site](http://newsitetest.regencycarrentals.com/)

I just tested it out on pingdom and scored a 91/100.

Also, pages with very little content, such as our contact page, run slow as well.

FYI, this is a test site so you might find random pics of my dog in strange locations.

Comment: What do you mean that it's running slow? Slow how? Give us some metrics or something. If it's scoring well on all those tests, that's an indicator it's reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome, open an incongnito page and open developer tools, click on network and then load your site. Now sort by time(latency). You will notice JCH Optimize, Autoptimize and WP-Optimize are taking up a lot of load time. Disable these plugins one by one to see if it makes any difference.

Also - I don't think you need three different plugins to optimize your site. One should be enough.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was Autoptimize. The funny thing is that my page speed scores went down significantly but my site is now working fine. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Autoptimize can slow down page download time if the page is not in a page caching cache and if the CSS/ JS is not in AO's cache either. AO 2.0 solves this by not aggregating inline CSS/ JS by default (which increases cache-ability of optimized CSS/ JS) and by a new minimizing-approach which makes minification 30% faster on average.